# How can I find all rows after the 2nd instance for a given value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My data looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove rows 3-6 since left and center values are the same. I also want to remove the last 4 rows. What is the easiest way to identify these rows?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Remove Duplicates command on the data ribbon. It was made for exactly this purpose.

Edit: Select the three columns, then click Data > Remove Duplicates

In the following dialog, tick the column(s) you want to include in the duplicate check. In this case it's only column A, so columns B and C have been deselected.

[image]

Confirm the dialog and Excel will remove the rows that qualify as duplicates.

[image]

Edit 2: If you want to keep the first two duplicates for each group, add the helper column that Kenneth L suggests, but with a slightly different formula. Use this formula in the helper column:

```
=(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)>1)
```

[image]

then remove duplicates with column A and the helper column ticked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice.  Except the OP wants to leave the 1st two of each group of dupes in place.

Comment: What are the odds that userxxxxxxxxxxx with 1 rep, will ever come back? Yeah.

Comment: @ejbytes Who cares? Maybe the user has not even been back after asking the question. Maybe the user will come back tomorrow for the first time since asking the question. Or not. But anyone who sees the question will see the edits to the answer, so by definition, answers are not written only for the original asker.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding a helper function at column D.
In cell D1, type the formula `=COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,B$1:B1,B1)>2` and drag this formula to fill column D.

You will see something like the image below:
[image]

You can easily filter those marked "TRUE" which should be deleted.

What the formula works is to count the number of rows above the current row has the same A.  For example, the formula in cell D4 will be `=COUNTIFS(A$1:A4,A4,B$1:B4,B4)>2`, i.e. counting how many of `A1:A4` contains the same value as `A4`, and how many of `B1:B4` contains the same value as `B4`. If more than 2 is found, it gives a TRUE otherwise a FALSE.